# Windows: curl with json data on the command line

Tags: json, curl, elasticsearch

I am running the following command in Windows prompt:

```
curl -XPUT http://127.0.0.1:9200/test-index/test-type/_mapping?pretty=true -d '{"test-type": {"properties": {"name": {"index": "analyzed", "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets", "boost": 1.0, "store": "yes", "type": "string"}}}}'
```

I get the following error:

```
{
  "error" : "ElasticsearchParseException[Failed to parse content to map]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): expected a
valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.compress.lzf.LZFCompressedStreamInput@45
4ed1d2; line: 1, column: 2]]; ",
  "status" : 400
}
```

I searched for solutions and found alternatives such as put json data in files, but I cannot use it for some reasons.

Thanks!

Comment: try using `"` and escaping the inner ones with `\"`.

Comment: @DanielA.White That should be an answer. With Windows, this is a must

Comment: @DanielA.White, that works! Could you please post it as the answer?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Windows's `cmd` doesn't support strings with single quotes. Use `"` and escape the inner ones with `\"`.

Comment: Thanks! It helps me greatly.

Comment: Also using 2 double-quotes for escaping inner double-quotes works, eg. `{ ""test"": 10 }` is like `{ \"test\": 10 }`.

Answer (score 8):

> "I searched for solutions and found alternatives such as put json data in files, but I cannot use it for some reasons"

This should work, with `hello.json` in temp. The `@` is requried.

```
c:\temp>curl -v -X PUT  \ 
             --data "@hello.json"  \
             -H "Content-Type:application/json"  \
             http://localhost:8080/api/myresource
```