# ArangoDB can't send request with curl

Tags: http, post, curl, d, arangodb

I can't unserstand what I am doing wrong, but when I am sending next request with curl, I am getting error:

```
echo {"id":1,"question":"aaa"},{"id":2,"question":"bbb?"} | curl -X POST --data-binary @- --dump - http://localhost:8529/_db/otest/_api/document/?collection=sitetestanswers


HTTP/1.1 100 (Continue)

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: ArangoDB
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 100

{"error":true,"errorMessage":"failed to parse json object: expecting EOF","code":400,"errorNum":600}
```

Any ideas? I tied wrap it's to `[`...`]`. Nothing do not help.
With `[`...`]` validator mark this as valid

Same with D. Here is my code:

```d
void sendQuestionsToArangoDB(Json questions)
{
    string collectionUrl = "http://localhost:8529/_db/otest/_api/document/?collection=sitetestanswers"; 

    auto rq = Request();
    rq.verbosity = 2;
    string s = `{"id":"1","question":"foo?"},{"id":2}`;
    auto rs = rq.post(collectionUrl, s, "application/json");
    writeln("SENDED");
}
```

--

```
 POST /_db/otest/_api/document/?collection=sitetestanswers HTTP/1.1
 Content-Length: 37
 Connection: Close
 Host: localhost:8529
 Content-Type: application/json

 HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
 Server: ArangoDB
 Connection: Close
 Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
 Content-Length: 100
 100 bytes of body received
```

For D I use this lib: https://github.com/ikod/dlang-requests
Same issue with vibed.

Comment: Show the curl command, at least! And reduce it to the minimum necessary to replicate the issue-I can't even scroll that long on my phone.

Comment: Can you mark your answer as 'accepted' if it fixed the problem for you?

Answer (score 3):

ArangoDB do not understand JSON if it's come ass array like `[...]`. It should be passed as key-value. So if you need pass array it should have key `mykey : []`.

Here is working code:

```
import std.stdio;
import requests.http;

void main(string[] args) 
{
    string collectionUrl = "http://localhost:8529/_db/otest/_api/document?collection=sitetestanswers"; 

    auto rq = Request();
    rq.verbosity = 2;
    string s = `{"some_data":[{"id":1, "question":"aaa"},{"id":2, "question":"bbb"}]}`;
    auto rs = rq.post(collectionUrl, s, "application/json");
    writeln("SENDED");
}
```

`otest` - DB name

`sitetestanswers` - collection name (should be created in DB)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '[{"id":1,"question":"aaa"},{"id":2,"question":"bbb?"}]'
```

should do the trick. You need to put ticks around the JSON. The array brackets are necessary otherwise this is not valid JSON.

Comment: Like this: `echo  '[{"id":1,"question":"aaa"},{"id":2,"question":"bbb?"}]' | curl -X POST --data-binary @- --dump - http://localhost:8529/_db/otest/_api/document/?collection=sitetestanswers` ? Same result :(

Comment: this is what i get back: [{"_id":"sitetestanswers/939","_key":"939","_rev":"939"},{"_id":"sitetestanswers/943","_key":"943","_rev":"943"}].
i cut and pasted your post here.

Comment: what can be wrong? Any ideas? 
http://img.ctrlv.in/img/16/05/04/572a5d4335db6.png

Comment: i was going to ask what shell you were using. i should have. i am not sure how to do proper windows shell escaping. you have the choice to use -d @data.json. put your json into the file without the ticks.

Comment: I do not think that it's problem in shell. I use ConEmu. The command with single json oblect is past fine:
`echo {"id":2,"question":"bbb?"} | curl -X POST --data-binary @- --dump - http://localhost:8529/_db/otest/_api/document/?collection=sitetestanswers`
the issue only when it's have two objects like example above

Comment: it's sure the proper escaping. look here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648473/windows-curl-with-json-data-on-the-command-line

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to send multiple documents. The data in the original question separates the documents by comma (`{"id":1,"question":"aaa"},{"id":2,"question":"bbb?"}`) which is invalid JSON. Thus the `failed to parse json object` answer from ArangoDB.

Putting the documents into angular brackets (`[ ... ]`) as some of the commentors suggested will make the request payload valid JSON again.

However, you're sending the data to a server endpoint that handles a *single* document. The API for POST `/_api/document/?collection=...` currently accepts a single document at a time. It does not work with multiple documents in a single request. It expects a JSON object, and whenever it is sent something different it will respond with an error code.

If you're looking for batch inserts, please try the API POST `/_api/import`, described in the manual here: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/develop/http/import/

This will work with multiple documents in a single request. ArangoDB 3.0 will also allow sending multiple documents to the POST `/_api/document?collection=...` API, but this version is not yet released. A technical preview will be available soon however.