# Flask API failing to decode JSON data. Error: "message": "Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I'm setting up a simple rest api using flask and flask-restful. Right now all I'm trying to do is create a post request with some Json data, and then return it just to see if it works. I always get the same error `"message": "Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"`

Below is my code

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


class Tester(Resource):
   def get(self):
       return {'about': 'Hello World'}

   def post(self):
       data_json = request.get_json(force=True)
       return {'you sent': data_json}


api.add_resource(Tester, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The curl request I am making to test this is below, I've also tried making request using postman

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{'username':"abc",'password':"abc"}' http://localhost:5000
```

Comment: In postman, do you have raw-> JSON (application/json) option selected?

Comment: @needtobe No I did not. Just tried it and I got a 200 response. Thank you. That said why doesn't it seem to work in the curl request?

Comment: Generate the cURL request code using Postman

Comment: Try curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"username\":\"abc\", \"password\":\"abc\"}" http://127.0.0.1:5000 instead.

Comment: @Pitto Just tried that. Works in postman. But moment I paste the curl request on to command line I get the same error

Comment: @FProlog try mine cURL posted above.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to select raw -> JSON (application/json) in Postman like this:

[image]

When it comes to your cURL request, [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28648868/8916412) explains that windows's command line lacks support of strings with single quotes, so use:

```sh
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"username\":\"abc\", \"password\":\"abc\"}" 127.0.0.1:5000
```

instead:

```sh
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{'username':"abc",'password':"abc"}' http://localhost:5000
```

`\` escapes `"` character.

Answer (score 3):

You also need to have the Content-Length header enabled.

[image: Without header]

[image: With header]

Comment: This was it for me, so strange!

Answer (score 2):

Some additional information in case you are using python script to test your flask api like me - you have to `dumps` before adding the dictionary to the data field.

```py
import requests
import json

response = requests.post(
    'http://localhost:5000', 
    data = json.dumps({'username':"abc",'password':"abc"}),
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    )
```

Comment: This answer solved my problem. Got rid of the JSON decode error and also converts `datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 3, 9, 47, 9, 427000)` to `2019-04-03 09:47:09.427000` on the fly.

`>>> json.dumps({'datetime':'datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 3, 9, 47, 9, 427000)'})`

`output: {'datetime':'2019-04-03 09:47:09.427000'}`

Answer (score 0):

The curl request (payload) is incorrect. Use double quotes in the payload.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"abc","password":"abc"}' http://localhost:5000
```

Comment: Single quote in your payload --> '{'.